# Sell bulk by colour or by part or by both

Tags: shopping, colour

I have 100’s of pounds of semi sorted Lego, mostly by colour.

Would it be beneficial to sort by colour and part to sell in bulk? Or sell a bulk lot of one colour but various bricks?

Answer (score 7):

It (obviously) depends on what people want to buy.

If someone wants to build something, and doesn't **totally** care what colors are used, then they'll want to buy categorized by shape. It's **so** much easier to find a red 2x4 in a bin of 2x4s than to find a red 2x4 in a bin of red pieces.

But if someone wants to build, say, Big Bird, then they'll just want yellow, and will want to buy categorized by color.

I think the former is **much** more common.

See also: [Organizing your LEGO Bricks](https://brickarchitect.com/guide/bricks/organization/)